# In SharePoint 2010, datasheet view for a list is not allowing me to update items

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In SharePoint 2010, datasheet view for a list is not allowing me to update items.
Its giving an error saying, "all the required fields are not included in the view, Please include all the required fields in the view before updating items"
My List has two content types (A & B) associated to it.
I have included all the required columns from two content types (A & B). Still not able to use datasheet view for updating items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few things to consider,

1) Make all the columns of two content types (A & B) optional. 
   Do it for List content type and Site content type.

2) You have to make all the list columns optional. For doing this, you have to first uncheck "Allow management of content types" from advanced settings of a list.
After doing this, you will be shownn all list columns with "Required" column as well. Now you can go to list column settings by selecting a list column and make it optional.

If you do not uncheck "Allow management of content types", you can't know whether list column is required or optional and you don't have a way to make it optional.Bookmark

Answer (score 0):

Please check the all views of the list. There will be one columns which is require but you did not include. Check the view settings.